# Case insensitive regex matching both à and À

Tags: java, regex, french

I faced that case independent regex like `/(?i)À/` doesn't match the line in lowercase like `à`.

I checked this in code and made sure that `"À".toLowerCase() == "à"`

Does case insensitive regex works only for english (or latin) characters?

Here's the sample of code which is supposed to return true, but returns false

`Pattern.compile("À", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("à").matches()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [java](/questions/tagged/java), you can specify the flags `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` and `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`, i.e.:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("À", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | 
                                             Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

With the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`:

> When this flag is specified then case-insensitive matching, when enabled by the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag, is done in a manner consistent with the Unicode Standard. By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being matched.

In another way, you can use the embedded flag expression. i.e.:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?iu)À");
```

The embedded flag expression can include [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), [`UNICODE_CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE), [`CANON_EQ`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CANON_EQ), [`UNIX_LINES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNIX_LINES), [`LITERAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL), [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) and [`COMMENTS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#COMMENTS).

Next, the list of flags that you can use with its corresponding embedded flag (if exists)::

```
+-------------------------+------+
| UNIX_LINES              | (?d) |
| CASE_INSENSITIVE        | (?i) |
| COMMENTS                | (?x) |
| MULTILINE               | (?m) |
| LITERAL                 |      |
| DOTALL                  | (?s) |
| UNICODE_CASE            | (?u) |
| CANON_EQ                |      |
| UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS | (?U) |
+-------------------------+------+
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it works

Comment: I'd add that this can also be done with `(?iu)À`

Comment: @RealSkeptic *Yep*. Using the embedded flag expression.